# ImageMagick library in CI on OpenShift RedHat not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, redhat, openshift

I have a codeigniter website and i cant get ImageMagick to work.

I have checked with phpinfo() and imagemagick is enabled on the server.

This is the config code for the library:

```
    $image_conf = array(
                'image_library'     => 'ImageMagick',
                'library_path'      => '/usr/bin/',
                  .....
```

I keep getting the same error: ***Image processing failed.  Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct.***

is `'library_path'      => '/usr/bin/'` ? I cant seem to find anything regarding this on their forums, people usually had different problems that were solved...

And i have no other problems with paths on the website or similar...

Here is some server information ask for more if you need:

```
$config['base_path']= "/var/lib/openshift/12341234...appcode/app-root/runtime/repo/php/";
$config['base_dir']= "/var/lib/openshift/1234324..appcode/app-root/runtime/repo/php/";
```

imagick 2.2.2

PHP 5.3.3, ZendServer

Linux

Apache/2.2.22 (Red Hat Enterprise Web Server)

Comment: If you have installed ImageMagic extension then you don't need to specify your path. PHP can generate it's object using, $image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

Comment: Hm, but i would like to use it with codeIgniters image manipulation library, and it uses the code from above...thus i need the correct library path, since then i can just call $this->image_lib->resize() and it does all the work.

Comment: In that case, you need to download the whole library (Bunch of class files) in PHP version (Not extension). Include in your configuration file 'library_path'. This is only way to configure it.

Comment: That just plain crazy :) ...ok thanks i'll try with new imagick to see how it goes.

Comment: This will help you, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
 I would check to see if you give the server write permission to the directory you are trying to save the images. Try a chmod 777 on the dir just to make sure.

If that doesn't work, I suggest you get to know MagickWand. http://www.magickwand.org/